# Highcharts plot bands rendered on top of all series

Tags: highcharts

Looks like a regression in 6.1.0 when upgrading from 5.0.14.
I create Y axis plot bands dynamically for a selected series by

```
chartObject.update({ yAxis: {plotBands: [...], plotLines: [...]} });
```

In this case whatever zIndex I assign to series or bands the series is rendered behind/below bands and is inaccessible interactively (e.g. tooltips are not displayed when hovering over points), bands get all mouse input. If I create the same bands right at the beginning together with series (before calling Highcharts.chart()), series remain accessible.
Even if I remove and then add series (recreate) after creating bands, it remains inaccessible.

Update:
Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zc79tcr/8/) to reproduce.
Issue disappears if I exclude accessibility.js or exporting.js or include 'exporting' after 'accessibility'. In other words, issue can be reproduced by including accessibility module after exporting module.
Click the "Update bands" button repeatedly.

Comment: Have you tried [zIndex](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.zIndex) option? Can you make a live example, e.g. on jsifddle?

Comment: I did try zIndex. So far I have failed to reproduce it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zc79tcr/3/ . In my project there're many other things which should not matter: MVC, jQuery, angularJS, bootstrap etc.

Comment: I have reproduced it in jsfiddle and updated my post accordingly. The culprit was the order of the inclusion of exporting and accessibility modules. Workaround is to link accessibility module before exporting one, or, to be safer, link it before any other module (or not at all).

Comment: It looks like a bug, I suggest to report it on [highcharts github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts)

Comment: created issue https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8392